# JavaScript: Highlight a row when I scroll up/down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, highlighting

On my web page, I a table inside a `DIV` that is scrollable.

When I scroll down, I want to highlight the center most viewable row in my table.

How would I do that?

I found the following script that is close to what I desire --> www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0093.html

But this works only on the `MouseOver` event. I want this to work on not just the MouseOver event but also when I simply scroll up/down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`scroll`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/scroll#fn) event.

For example: (**EDIT**: Finally tested)

```
var scrollElem = $('div#panel-hlisting-all');
scrollElem.scroll(function() {
    var scrollElemPos = scrollElem.offset();

    var newCenter = $(document.elementFromPoint(
        scrollElemPos.left + scrollElem.width()  / 2,
        scrollElemPos.top  + scrollElem.height() / 2)
    ).closest('.hlisting');

    if(newCenter.is(".CenterRow")) return;
    $('.CenterRow').removeClass("CenterRow");
    newCenter.addClass('CenterRow');
});
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code to work with a specific element's scrollbar.
**3<sup>rd</sup> EDIT**: I updated the code to prevent flicker.

Comment: But I only want to highlight one (1) row, that being the center most row in the scroll window. Make Sense?

Comment: Meaning, let's imagine that I have 10 row in my table but my viewable scroll window can only display at most 3 rows at a time. So initially, row 1-2-3 will be displayed. In this case, row 2 would be highlighted. Now let's say the person scrolls down a bit and rows 2-3-4 are now displayed. Now, row 3 would be the only row highlighted. Scroll much futher, let's now say rows 7-8-9 a viewable. As such, now row 8 is highlighted.

Comment: My code should do exactly that.  Note that I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Nope :(  I just tried the code above and my page now won't load. Does the JQuery scroll event need any libraries other than the core/base JQuery?

Comment: @SLake, any suggestions? You're code looks promising but it's freezing my page from loading

Comment: You mind sharing how I would debug using Firebug. I just installed the Firefox plugin but don't know how to use it

Comment: I see the DOM tab of Firebug. I assume I want to look at that tab but don't know what I'm looking at :(  thanks in advance

Comment: It gives an error saying your code above is "missing ) after argument list .closest('tr').addClass('CenterRow');"

Comment: Also, does you script above work on the DIV scroll window or the actual page scrollbar?  I want this to only fire on the DIV scrollbar and not the overall page scrollbar

Comment: I changed the code to be ".closest('tr').addClass('CenterRow'));" (note the additional ")" at the end. However, now I receive an Firebug error stating the "elementFromPoint is not a function"

Comment: `elementFromPoint` should be a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.elementFromPoint.  Check the spelling.

Comment: Almost working. The updated code above now doesn't error and is fired on the DIV scrollbar ... BUT, it doesn't appear to be adding the CSS CenterRow. I added to my CSS .CenterRow{background:red} but the row never seems to turn read. I added a console.log('did the person scroll') and that prints out correctly. Any idea why my .CenterRow CSS might be added?

Comment: Last thing to note, instead of a table - I am using my own custom DIV. The structure is <div class="listing">...</div><div class="listing">...</div>.  So I replaced ".closest('tr').addClass('CenterRow');" with ".closest('.listing').addClass('CenterRow');" though it still doesn't seem to be adding the CenterRow CSS element :(  Any ideas

Comment: Check what `elementFromPoint` and `closest` are returning using `console.log`.

Comment: They return [].  When I put "console.log($(document.elementFromPoint(scrollElem.scrollLeft() + scrollElem.width() / 2,
                                scrollElem.scrollTop() + scrollElem.height() / 2))
        .closest('.hlisting').addClass('CenterRow'));" in my code, it prints out to Firebug just "[]"

Comment: @SLake, I have updated my original post to include a link to my live web site so you can view it

Comment: The problem was that my code was getting the location relative to `scrollElem` and looking for the element relative to `document`.  I fixed it; try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilize the [jQuery Scroll event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/scroll).